# In how many different ways can you order in line the letters of the word AAAAABBB?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many different ways can you order in line the letters of the word AAAAABBB?
I was thinking - I have $8!$ for the whole letters including repeats, and then because each word repeats $5!$ for the A's and $3!$ times for the B's - divide by $5!\cdot3!$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  Phrased differently, you just need to pick $3$ slots out of $8$ to place the $B's$, so $\binom 83$.